# How to add class to a collection of elements sequentially?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to add a class to a each element in a collection. I want add a classs to the elemnt then wait a sec or two then add the class to the next one in the collection.

But when I use this code it just adds the class to each one at once.

```
for (var i = 0; i < article.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(article[i]).addClass('something';
        }, 10000);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting a bunch of timeouts 10 seconds from the same moment in time, so they will all execute 10 seconds later at once.  You need to chain them together so that each timeout handler invokes the next timeout:

```
var i = 0;
var callback;

callback = function () {
    if (i < article.length) {
        $(article[i]).addClass('something');

        ++i;
        setTimeout(callback, 10000);
    }
};

setTimeout(callback, 10000);
```

Comment: Is their a way to reverse the effect? So removeClass starting with the last? Thanks.

Comment: @mtwallet Yes, use `var i = article.length - 1;` instead, for the condition use `i >= 0` instead of `i < article.length`, use `removeClass()` instead of `addClass()`, and do `--i` instead of `++i`.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
 (function step(i){         
     if( i < article.length ){
          $(article[i]).addClass('some_class');
          setTimeout(function(){ step(i+1) },10000);
     }         
 })(0);
```

Comment: You can retain the elegance without cheating (not indenting function) by using `$.proxy( step, null, i+1 )` :P

Comment: @Esailija I don't think,that it is more elegant with `$.proxy`. )

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var x = setInterval("javascript",ms);
```

and it wall call whatever is in the code section over and over again every "ms" until you call the

```
clearInterval(x);
```

function

Answer (score 0):

An approach without having to chain calls:

```
for (var i = 0; i < article.length; i++) {
    (function(_i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(article[_i]).addClass('something');
    }, 10000+_i*1000);
    })(i);
}
```

It's pretty unlikely the overhead from adding a CSS class will be significant enough to make this not behave as desired.