# Add class to a collection of elements sequentially starting with last element

Tags: javascript, addclass, sequential

I wanted to add a class to a collection of elements sequentially. I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250518/how-to-add-class-to-a-collection-of-elements-sequentially).

For reference here is the code from that article:

```
var i = 0;
var callback;

callback = function () {
    if (i < article.length) {
       $(article[i]).addClass('something');

       ++i;
       setTimeout(callback, 10000);
    }
};

setTimeout(callback, 10000);
```

I would now like to remove the class starting with the last element, so in effect reverse the order of what will be an animation.

Can anyone help? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: so start at the length minus one and subtract and use removeClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start `i` as `article.length` loop in the other direction

```
var i = article.length;
var callback;

callback = function () {
    if (i--) {
       $(article[i]).removeClass('something');
       setTimeout(callback, 10000);
    }
};

setTimeout(callback, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the `setTimeout` method works, jQuery provides a way to achieve that far more elegantly:

```
$(".article").each(function() {
    var d = $(this);
    $("body").queue(function(next) {  
        d.addClass("foo");
        next();
    }).delay(200)
})
```

To iterate in reverse order, first add this small "plugin":

```
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
```

and then:

```
$(".article").reverse().each(function() {
    var d = $(this);
    $("body").queue(function(next) {  
        d.addClass("foo");
        next();
    }).delay(200)
})
```

Comment: Hi thg435. Thanks for the reply it is indeed more elegant but I am not using jQuery this time.

Comment: @mtwallet: so, `$` and `addClass` in your post are from another library?

Comment: yes they are and its my fault for not mentioning it in the post. I am using ChocolateChipUI which has it's own jQuery like syntax. However I do use jQuery a lot so your answer is still relevant and I did learn something as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To do reverse:

```
var i = article.length - 1;
var callback;

callback = function () {
    if (i >= 0) {
       $(article[i]).removeClass('something');

       --i;
       setTimeout(callback, 10000);
    }
};

setTimeout(callback, 10000);
```

Comment: This won't remove the class of `article[0]`

Comment: It will also attempt `$(undefined).removeClass('something');` because `article[article.length]` will be _undefined_.

Comment: that should correct, but I'll upvote your answer. It's better implemented than mine.